# Check if a field content is not in the multiple field in other table

Tags: mysql, select

I got `players` table and `host` field in it, I also got a second table called `bans` with the following fields: `host`, `second_host`, `ip`. I need to check if `players`.`host` content field is **not** equal to any of those three fields in the `bans` table, with one condition: `WHERE expiry >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

I've already built this one, but as you can see, there are three conditions in the bans table, and now I don't know what to do.

```
SELECT * FROM players
WHERE host NOT IN (
      SELECT host 
      FROM bans 
      WHERE expires >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
)
```

Now I'd have to do the same for three other fields (`second_host` and `ip`). Is that will be possible to do in one query? If so, please post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to do this in a join condition:

```
SELECT players.*
FROM   players
  LEFT JOIN bans 
    ON players.host IN (bans.host, bans.second_host, bans.ip)
   AND (bans.expires >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() OR bans.expires = -1)
WHERE  bans.PK IS NULL;  -- use primary key from bans table in place of PK
```

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Yea, good point but this one is selecting `only` the banned players, while I want to skip selecting them and select only those without banishment (so when expires is lower than UNIX_TIMESTAMP or a row doesnt exist in the bans table).

Comment: @Cyclone: See my revised answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, but I want to add the another condition for the permament banishment, so when the `expires` is set to `-1` then it wont select the player I have tried: `AND bans.expires >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() OR bans.expires = -1` but it failed (doesnt select any rows in results). Could you please add that last condition?

Comment: @Cyclone: See my revised answer.

Comment: There is another problem. When the query is done, it doesn't select the `id` field and `host` field from `players` table. Could you look on it?

Comment: @Cyclone: It's more likely that it does, but your application is not handling column name collisions for you.  See my revised answer to ensure that only columns from the `players` table are selected (and thereby avoid such collisions).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   players 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   bans 
                   WHERE  (players.host = bans.host 
                             OR players.host = bans.second_host 
                             OR players.host = bans.ip ) 
                          AND bans.expires >= Unix_timestamp());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM players
WHERE host NOT IN (
  SELECT host FROM bans WHERE expires >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
  UNION
  SELECT second_host from bans WHERE expires >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
  UNION
  SELECT ip from bans WHERE expires >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
)
```

Or

```
SELECT * from players
WHERE host not in (SELECT host.....)
AND host not in (SELECT second_host....)
AND host not in (SELECT ip....)
```

Comment: Union is very bad idea, you are scanning three times the ban table.